# check if variable exists in the workspace with cellfun

Tags: matlab, exists

Consider the following example:

```
dat1 = 1;
dat2 = 2;

Variables = {'dat1','dat2'};

a = cellfun(@(x)exist(x,'var'),Variables);

for i = 1:length(Variables);
    a2(i) = exist(Variables{i},'var');
end
```

why do 'a' and 'a2' return different values i.e. why does using cellfun not state that the variables exist in the workspace? what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, it's truly strange. I've checked that functional expression (with `@`): 1. can access the variables in the environment -and- 2. preserves the right type of the argument. Both are true, which is really strange. Seems to me that that you've just found bug in `cellfun` or `exist`! Congratulations :)

Comment: @Kate: What you're missing is that every anonymous function gets its own workspace (took me a while as well). See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand what's going on here:

When you call an anonymous function, it creates its own workspace, as would any normal function. However, this new workspace will not have access to the caller workspace.

Thus

```
funH = @(x)exist(x,'var')
```

will only ever return 1 if you supply `'x'` as input (`funH('x')`), since its entire workspace consists of the variable `'x'`.

Consequently,

```
funH = @(x)exist('x','var')
```

will always return 1, regardless of what you supply as input.

There are two possible ways around that:

(1) Use `evalin` to evaluate in the caller's workspace

```
 funH =  @(x)evalin('caller',sprintf('exist(''%s'',''var'')',x))
```

(2) Use the output of `whos`, and check against the list of existing variables

```
 Variables = {'dat1','dat2'};
 allVariables = whos;
 a3 = ismember(Variables,{allVariables.name})
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If new workspace doesn't have access to callers workspace, how does this code `b = 3; feval(@(x) b+x, 2)` returns `5` then? Could you explain, please?

Comment: @zplesivcak: in adding `b` to the definition of the anonymous function, you add a copy of it to the workspace of the anonymous function. If you change the value of `b` after defining the anonymous function, `b` inside the anonymous function doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write the `cellfun` line as:

```
a = cellfun(@(x) exist('x','var'),Variables);
```

to make it equivalent to the for loop.
See also how to use `exist` in [Matlab's Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) examples...

**EDIT:**

After (I think I'm) understanding Jonas's answer, the line above will always return true regardless if `dat1=1` or `dat1=[]`. In order to use `cellfun` see Jonas answer...

Comment: I was wrong. Your function will return true at all times, regardless of the input.

Comment: From the example on cellfun it does not show that the `x` should be put between quotes. `Cpositives = cellfun(@(x) x(x>0), C, 'UniformOutput',false)` Therefore I don't think this is it.